# Is there a way to replace last occurrence of match using a shell variable substitution?

Tags: bash, scripting, wildcards, replace

```
% x=abracadabra
% echo ${x//a/o}
obrocodobro
```

Hmph...

Is there a way to replace the *last* occurrence of a pattern using shell substitions (IOW, without rolling out `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, etc.)?

Comment: Nope there isn't

Comment: @llua: dang ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Note: this replaces a trailing occurrence - not quite the same as "the last occurrence"*

From the [Bash reference manual Section 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
:

> ```
> ${parameter/pattern/string}
> ```
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the
>   longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string. If
>   pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with
>   string. Normally only the first match is replaced. If pattern begins
>   with ‘#’, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of
>   parameter. **If pattern begins with ‘%’, it must match at the end of the
>   expanded value of parameter.** If string is null, matches of pattern are
>   deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted. If the nocasematch
>   shell option (see the description of shopt in The Shopt Builtin) is
>   enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of
>   alphabetic characters. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution
>   operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the substitution operation is applied to
>   each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
>   list.

So

```
$ x=abracadabra
$ echo "${x/%a/o}"
abracadabro
```

Comment: What do you mean by trailing occurrence? Can you provide an example showing the difference (i.e. when this would not work)?

Comment: @MrJman006 it means the character (or substring) that you want to replace must be at the end of the string - so `${x/%r/s}` won't replace the last (second) `r` in `x=abracadabra` for example (you'd need to extend the match to the end of the string like `${x/%ra/sa}`)

Comment: Got it! That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Doesn't work for x="aba "

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with shell substitutions its just a bit tricky. You basically grab everything before the pattern insert your replacement and than grab everything after the pattern. For your example that would look like this:

```
    x=abracadabra
    echo "${x%a*}o${x##*a}"
```

EDIT: Or just do what steeldriver suggested in the comments.

Comment: This works nicely!